# Knife tool keeps popping up

Tags: knife-tool

I've accidentally clicked something with the mouse and now when ever I left click the knife tool comes up. I've tried pressing esc, however when I left click again it comes up, I've tried load factory settings, however when I start a new page it happens again.

Comment: Make sure you haven't the Knife tool selected in the Toolbar.

Comment: The select box is selected

Comment: If this is happening in the new project also then probably you have by mistake changes some setting , try going to the keymap and see what are the input settings for the knife tool , and also try to see what you left mouse button is supposed to do , what i think that this much should solve the problem

Comment: It worked! Thank you!